# How to view model binding exceptions locally

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-4.6

I have an ASP.NET web app running in an Azure app service.

After doing a profiler trace, I noticed these three .NET exceptions:

```
Requested value 'Asc' was not found.

Asc is not a valid value for SortOrder.

The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Enums.SortOrder' failed. See the inner exception for more information.
```

They all have this stack trace:

```
mscorlib.ni![COLD] System.Enum+EnumResult.SetFailure
mscorlib.ni!System.Enum.Parse
system.ni!
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.ValueProviders.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.ValueProviders.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleListType
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.ValueProviders.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.TypeConverterModelBinder.BindModel
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContextExtensions.Bind
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.Binders.CompositeModelBinder.BindModel
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding+<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__12.MoveNext
mscorlib!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsyncCore
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext
mscorlib!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[System.__Canon].Start
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.ExecuteAsync
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher+<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext
mscorlib!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[System.__Canon].Start
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync
system.net.http.ni!
system.web.http!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync
system.net.http.ni!
autofac.integration.webapi!Autofac.Integration.WebApi.CurrentRequestHandler.SendAsync
system.net.http.ni!
Rend.invgen.invoicegateway.api!Rend.invgen.InvoiceGateway.Api.Handlers.RequestResponseLogHandler.SendNextAsync
Rend.invgen.invoicegateway.api!Rend.invgen.InvoiceGateway.Api.Handlers.RequestResponseLogHandler+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<SendAsync>b__0
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler.PostCallback
system.web.ni!
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem
mscorlib.ni!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback
```

My action method which is causing this issue looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync(SortOrder sort = SortOrder.Ascending)
{
    // sort something
}
```

This action method is called using arguments  such as `Asc`.

Even though this seems to cause .NET exceptions, the default value of `Ascending` gets used if it can't bind a value.

My question is, why am I unable to view the `Requested value Asc was not found` exceptions locally?

When I run the app locally and pass `Asc` and `Desc`, no Exceptions are thrown, and I can't see any Exceptions in the Debug window either.

Comment: complete wild guess. but could it be related to the operating system executing the code. e.g. different underlying API layer? One OS works another errors? If not please ignore me.

Comment: Turns out there is no Exception, however there is an error in the ModelState object for the sort param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Binding an `Enum` expects the integer value corresponding to the value.

If you want to supply a `string` value, you must tell the modelbinder that by adding an attribute to your `Enum` type declaration, like this:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(EnumModelBinder))]
public enum SortOrder
{
}
```

or you can add an attribute to your property in the model, like this:

```
[BindProperty(BinderType = typeof(EnumModelBinder))]
public SortOrder MySortOrder {get;set;}
```

Now the modelbinder should be able to handle strings. Of course the strings must match the enum values exact.

BTW: Modelbinding, that fails, does not throw exceptions, it simply ignores the values, meaning properties will get their default values.

Comment: Model binding does actually throw exceptions, they're just handled.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced and able to resolve, please follow the below steps

- Below is the folder structure

[image]

**ActionModel.cs**

- To bind the data to the view we are using action model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVC_Sort
{
    public class ActionModel
    {
        public ActionModel()
        {
            ActionsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        [Display(Name="Names")]
        public int ActionId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActionsList { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

**ActionType.cs**

- A list of Enum to display in sorted order

```
namespace MVC_Sort
{
    public enum ActionType
    {
        MMM = 1,
        RRR = 2,
        AAA = 3,
        JJJ = 4,
        EEE = 5,
        SSS = 6,
        HHH = 7
    }

}
```

**ActionTypeModel.cs**

- In view it is used to display the Enum values and label names in the output

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MVC_Sort
{
    public class ActionTypeModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Names")]
        public int ActionId { get; set; }
        public ActionType ActionTypeList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

- The Action method in the **HomeController** is executed when requested

```
namespace MVC_Sort.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ActionModel model = new ActionModel();
            IEnumerable<ActionType> actionTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ActionType))
                                                       .Cast<ActionType>();

            var res= actionTypes.OrderBy(enm => enm.ToString()).ToArray();

            model.ActionsList = from action in res
                                select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = action.ToString(),
                                    Value = ((int)action).ToString()
                                };

            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult ActionTypes()
        {
            ActionTypeModel model = new ActionTypeModel();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

- It is the Html page displayed when executed

```
model MVC_Sort.ActionModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.ActionId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ActionId, Model.ActionsList)
```

**Extension.cs**

- It is used to fetch or retrieve Enum values from **ActionType**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace MVC_Sort
{
    public static class Extension
    {

        public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                                                                    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
                                                                                    TEnum selectedValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))
                                        .Cast<TEnum>();

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
                                                select new SelectListItem()
                                                {
                                                    Text = value.ToString(),
                                                    Value = value.ToString(),
                                                    Selected = (value.Equals(selectedValue))
                                                };

            return SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper,expression, items);
        }
    }
}
```

- After the above steps Click on **debug** => **Start debugging**. After it will open the below one in the browser in Sorted order

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. It was "why am I unable to view the `Requested value Asc was not found` exceptions locally?" And the answer was provided by Poul Bak: "BTW: Modelbinding, that fails, does not throw exceptions, it simply ignores the values, meaning properties will get their default values."